# Flickering issue in chart when in override the draw method of scale in Chart JS

Tags: charts, chart.js

This is the Fiddle containing my issue as you can see their is a flickering when I hover on chart.

Can any one from ChartJS help to solve the issue?

Let me know if you can you help me solve the flickering issue the reason I have made change in prototype is that I need to make label left align which ChartJS is not providing.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/nishantprajapati/u8a40rt5/97/`
```

Comment: 404 on the url.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nishantprajapati/u8a40rt5/97/

Comment: @Rotemya can you please try now ?

Comment: Now the Url is valid.